# windowsupdate troubles on windowsxp after april 2014, plus an explorer error message

Tags: windows-xp, installation, windows-explorer, windows-installation

I've spent the last couple of days trying to install
windows xp from a cd onto my desktop. The installtion is successful,
and I can activate windows, but cannot run windows update.
The error I receive from windows update is:

```
Error number: 0x80240036
```

I understand that after april 2014 microsoft is no
longer developing new patches, but I have presumed
that customers would continue to have access
to all the patches that where made up to this date.

How can I install these patches? Is this possible?

As mentioned, I can install windows and activate, but cannot run windowsupdate (`Error number: 0x80240036`).

---

Seperately, there is an error with a windows explorer pull down menu (item) that asks:

```
Is this copy of windows legal?
```

How can I get rid of this message? I am not running a pirated, or illegal copy of windows and this message should not be there.
I want continue running windows xp without windows update, but I need to get rid of this windows explorer error message.

Comment: Hmm, Microsoft REALLY want you to get rid of XP. I mean REALLY! Unless you have an extended support agreement with them, you would need to be pretty desperate at this point to be using it. Sorry I can't help with an answer.

Comment: 0x80240036 = ERROR_NETWORK_BUSY (The network is busy)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get windowsupate working, and get the windows update message `Error number: 0x80240036` resolved.

I did this by downloading patches directly from microsoft (as an .exe (executable) download)
instead of going through windowsupdate .

There was a post earlier with this information, but since then is no longer seen.

The patches that where needed to get windowsupdate working or resolve error message `Error number: 0x80240036` are:

(1) Internet Explorer patches

*WindowsXP-KB932823-v3-x86-ENU.exe*

*IE8-WindowsXP-x86-ENU.exe*

(2) Windows Service Pack 3 (SP3)

*WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU*

Note that the windows installation CD was Windows XP Professional and with Service Pack 2 (SP2).

This indicates that windows update for windows xp is still in fact operational after April 2014, and patches released up until the end-of-life (eol) date of Microsoft Windows XP are still available, however additional patches are not expected after this eol date.

---

after installing all of these patches I still receive the message under windows explorer that "`is this copy of windows legal?`"

this is a clean and legal installation of windows ... is there a way to remove this? Seeing this message is really irritating and frustrating.

When you click on the help item `is this copy of windows legal?` it opens a web page at the following address: `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/default.aspx`.
This appears to be a bug on behalf of microsoft ... I have been able to activate windows and more.

Answer (score 0):

All the updates for this system are in via windows update. The web site reports that there are no further patches to install, and the system is current as per `windowsupdate.microsoft.com`.

Unfortunately, the help menu item via `c:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe` is still showing "`Is this copy of Windows Legal?`"

I have been doing some research, and found some ways to validate that my system is indeed clean and legal. These include: `Start Menu > Programs > Accessories > Systems Tools > Activate Windows`.

The Windows Activation applications indicates that `Windows is already activated. Click OK to exit`. Therefore, the system has been successfully activated, and it can be rerun at a given time to confirm that this is indeed so.

There is also a Windows Genuine Advantage Web site found at `http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/validate/`) that confirms the windows system is genuine. Specifically, the result seen is:

```
Because Windows installed on your PC is genuine,
enjoy the security, reliability and protection it provides.
```

On two fronts, the system has been confirmed as correct.

Lastly, a utility has been found that does just about the same. It called `MGADiag.exe` that is published by Microsoft. The output again confirms that the system is considered as needed.

**With all this in mind, it looks like microsoft has an active bug with Windows Explorer (explorer.exe).** Meaning that, the help menu item should not be displayed.

Is there any way to get rid of this menu item (`Is this copy of Windows Legal?`)? I consider it very pesky and troublesome ... especially when there is no reason for it to be there. I am to consider communicating with Microsoft soon, or posting this problem on their forums.

I want to continue using Windows XP, but find difficulties continuing without this menu item being corrected. I do not specifically mind that it is no longer to be receiving microsoft updates.

Answer (score 0):

When using windows explorer, if you have the status bar enabled and highlight `Is this copy of Windows Legal?` then you will see the following under the status bar:

> Displays instructions and information to determine if Microsoft
>   software is genuine.

After a bit of study on this topic it looks like the web site and message are not just for the operating system but for all of the contents of the/a computer. Therefore this information/legal notice is meant to notify users of bad software that may be found on a computer via Windows Explorer, not solely Windows XP for instance ... kind of a confusing topic ...